# Visual Studio Code: Failed to apply ESLint fixes to the document

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, linter

I am using Visual Studio Code 1.6.1, with latest version of ESLint extension installed and enabled. 
I have

```js
"eslint.options": {
  "rules": {
    ...
  }
}
```

in my vs-code user settings.
I was able to autofix my js files with the auto command "eslint.executeAutofix", but from maybe my last update of vs-code I am receiving the following error:

```html
Failed to apply ESLint fixes to the document. Please consider opening an issue with steps to reproduce.
```

Can somebody please help me or point me in direction where I can fix this issue?

Comment: Still issue persists. I noticed that eslint is working on new projects but in my current one it doesnt. Is there anything I could check?

Answer (score 20):

For anyone who bumps into the same issue. To troubleshoot, try running `npx eslint path/to/your/file` to see the actual eslint output.

In my case it was missing Prettier plugin:

> `Failed to load plugin 'prettier' declared in '.eslintrc.js » @react-native-community/eslint-config': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-prettier'`

Answer (score 0):

Somehow npm install eslint --save-dev fixed the issue.
Now it is working even after npm uninstall eslint --save-dev.
Strange...

Answer (score 0):

Run `eslint lint .\filename` on your file and see what it says.

In my case it was `Error: unreachable`. Then I started deleting small chunks of my code and running `eslint lint .\filename` over and over again untill I found the exact line that caused the issue. Turns out I made a stupid mistake using `??` in js file instead of `||`

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue and wanted to share my solution:

For me `npx eslint path/to/your/file` ran just fine, but I had a custom eslint config in my settings.json that was malformed so that's why the command failed in vscode only.

I realized that when I opened the eslint output ("View" => "Output" or click on the ESLint tab in the editor footer) and there I saw some errors.

The message `Please consider opening an issue with steps to reproduce.` was not so helpful here, maybe `Please check your ESLint output for errors.` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which was resolved after running `npm run lint` that displayed:

```
Configuration for rule "object-curly-spacing" is invalid:
        Severity should be one of the following: 0 = off, 1 = warn, 2 = error (you passed '4').
```

A simple mistake on my part in providing the incorrect config value, but the error only showed up in the terminal after calling the npm command. Check if your `eslintrc.json` has invalid rules!